# Not sure how to connect an HTML input button to a new ActionResult function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm very new to Razor MVC and I can't figure out how to wire an HTML input element click function to an ActionResult. Here is my code:

I took this code from a Login.cshtml file in the project and put it in Index.cshtml:

```
@model S2GPortal.Models.LoginModel

.
.
.

    <section id="featured">
    <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Log in Form</legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
                </li>
            </ol>
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
        </fieldset>
        <p>
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register")*@ if you don't have an account.
        </p>
    }
    </section>
```

This would, in turn, call a Login ActionResult method on an AccountController controller. When it was in the Login view. Since I've put it in the Index view, the Login method no longer gets called, and I can't figure out how to rewire it to look in the same controller. I'm not sure how MVC knew to call that specific Login ActionResult before. Here is the controller:

```
 public class AccountController : BaseController
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/Login
        [Inject]
        public ISystemUserRepository SystemUserRepository { get; set; }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
               string currentUser = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
               int test = 1;
            }
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                PortalSession.User = SystemUserRepository.GetByEmail(model.UserName);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
```

So, In summary, How does a view know to look into a specific controller for an ActionResult to call, and how does a line like this:  know which ActionResult to call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use this overload of `Html.BeginForm`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
{
   // your form elements
}
```

**1) First Parameter is ActionName**

**2) Second Controller Name**

**3) Third Form Method in your case it will be post as we are posting data**

**4) and fourth is route values**

your final view will be like this:

```
@model S2GPortal.Models.LoginModel


<section id="featured">
    <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Log in Form</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
            </fieldset>
        }
    </section>
```

Now on click of submit button your form will be posted on **Login** Action of **Account** Controller and rememeber form will only be posted with `<input type="submit"/>`, button or link will not work.